# why a projective transormation of a non singular curve gives a non singular cuve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I was reading a book which has the following exersise.Suppose that V is a nonsingular projective curve and T is a
projective transformation. Prove that T(V ) is also a nonsingular projective
curve.
What I am thinking is that V must be the vanishing locus of a homogeneous polynomial P. So if I want to show that T(V) is a non singular projective curve I first need to show that is the zero locus of some homogeneous polynomial Q and then that the gradient at those points is non-zero. How can I find such Q?
Thank you in advance

Comment: This should just be the chain rule.